# Fill Datatable with Variable dont work. But if i put the exact same value to a php site and request it with ajax. It works.... Why?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, datatables

This is in the variable "test":

```
{"data":[{"HistChar_ID":"4","Vorname":"Garnier","Nachname":"de
 Naplouse"},{"HistChar_ID":"2","Vorname":"Robert","Nachname":"de
 Sable"},{"HistChar_ID":"7","Vorname":"Ibn","Nachname":"Dschubair"},{"HistChar_ID":"6","Vorname":"Baha
 ad-Din","Nachname":"ibn
 Schaddad"},{"HistChar_ID":"1","Vorname":"Richard","Nachname":"L\u00f6wenherz"},{"HistChar_ID":"5","Vorname":"Wilhelm","Nachname":"von
 Montferrat"}]}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="thead1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1">HistChar_ID</th>
            <th class="th2">Vorname</th>
            <th class="th3">Nachname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="tfoot1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1">HistChar_ID</th>
            <th class="th2">Vorname</th>
            <th class="th3">Nachname</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

An the following Code Wont fill the Datatable.

```
$('#example').DataTable({       
    data: test, 
    columns: [
        { data: 'HistChar_ID'  },
        { data: 'Vorname' },
        { data: 'Nachname' },
    ]
```

it throws an Error like this:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter
> 'HistChar_ID' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
> error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I tried so much. But if i take whats inside of "test" and put it into a php and use ajax it works just fine with this.

```
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: 'RESOURCES/PHP/Searchfield.php',
        columns: [
            { data: 'HistChar_ID' },
            { data: 'Vorname' },
            { data: 'Nachname' },

        ]
```

PHP/Searchfield

```php
include 'connection.php';

$searchstuff = $_GET['Searchfield'];

$sql = "select * FROM historischercharacter WHERE Vorname LIKE '%$searchstuff%' OR Nachname LIKE '%$searchstuff%' ORDER BY Nachname" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));

$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}


echo json_encode(array('data'=>$emparray));

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Can someone explain me why? Is it impossible to fill the Datatable with a variable?? I just dont get it...

Comment: So, what exactly is in the Searchfield.php code? We don't have anything to compare to your raw data.

Comment: The `data` option expects an array of data records. You passed `test` - which is not that; but instead is an object, that has an array of records under the `data` property. So this should be `data: test.data` then ...?

Comment: I added the php to the question. Echo json_encode etc. give the exact same back as in the "test" variable.

Comment: Anyway, if you look at the examples in the documentation, the hard-coded array being passed into the table doesn't have the outer `data` property, it's just a simple array: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html . I don't use datatables but I'd guess that's the issue. Presumably the requirements when defining an AJAX data source are different. You can see the same thing here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/data . Always read the documentation!

Comment: ...and yes, the AJAX option requires a different structure: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax . So all the info to answer your question already exists in the datatables documentation.

Comment: @CBroe Now i didnt get an Error, but the Datatable tells me "No data available in table"

Comment: "_the Datatable tells me "No data available in table"_" - You need to show us the relevant code - preferrably as a working, runnable code snippet. When I use your JavaScript data like this: `var test = {"data":[{"HistChar_ID":"4", ... }] };` and then use `data: test.data` in the DataTable, everything works as expected, as @CBroe suggested it would. Just to note, I had to fix the data you show in the question by removing the line breaks.

Comment: The basic answer to your question _"why..?"_ is: DataTables needs to be told where to find the array `[ ... ]` which contains the row data. Once DataTables knows where that array is located, it can automatically iterate over the elements of that array - and each element will be used to build a row of data for the HTML table. Elements can themselves be arrays - or they can (as in your case) be objects `{ ... }`. (Just to note, an Ajax `dataSrc` source expects the default name of the JSON array to be `data`.)

Comment: I will try to add a snippet tomorrow. Cant do it now. But thanks so far for any answers. For me it is not solved.

Comment: Not sure what else you need to show? Just remove the "data" property from your object as we've advised. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nx247dy5/

Comment: Finaly it Works. It needed something like this: var Test3 = jQuery.parseJSON(Test);

Variable "Test" was interpreted as a String i think. And "Test3" is an Object. Thx for all the Answers

Comment: Ah ok. That was not clear from your question. You did not show, with actual code, how specifically you were defining and populating the `test` variable

Comment: Yep was my first Question here, sorry for that. Will be more specific next time. Anyway it helped me a lot to find the Problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the examples in the documentation, the hard-coded array being passed into the table doesn't have the outer `data` property, it's just an array by itself - see https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html . You can see the same thing here as well: https://datatables.net/reference/option/data

The requirements when defining an AJAX data source are different. As per the example at https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax by default you must supply an object with a "data" property as per the structure you've shown us in your question.

So it's simply that the requirements for each type of data source are different. Always read the documentation!

Demo of how to set the data source using a variable, with your variable. Note the absence of the "data" property...instead "test" is just a plain array:

```js
var test = [{
    "HistChar_ID": "4",
    "Vorname": "Garnier",
    "Nachname": "de Naplouse"
  }, {
    "HistChar_ID": "2",
    "Vorname": "Robert",
    "Nachname": "de Sable"
  }, {
    "HistChar_ID": "7",
    "Vorname": "Ibn",
    "Nachname": "Dschubair"
  }, {
    "HistChar_ID": "6",
    "Vorname": "Baha ad-Din",
    "Nachname": "ibn Schaddad"
  }, {
    "HistChar_ID": "1",
    "Vorname": "Richard",
    "Nachname": "L\u00f6wenherz"
  }, {
    "HistChar_ID": "5",
    "Vorname": "Wilhelm",
    "Nachname": "von Montferrat"
  }];

$('#example').DataTable({
  data: test,
  columns: [{
      data: 'HistChar_ID'
    },
    {
      data: 'Vorname'
    },
    {
      data: 'Nachname'
    },
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="thead1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1">HistChar_ID</th>
            <th class="th2">Vorname</th>
            <th class="th3">Nachname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="tfoot1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1">HistChar_ID</th>
            <th class="th2">Vorname</th>
            <th class="th3">Nachname</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a JavaScript variable which does not require you to change the data you show in your question:

```
var test = { "data": [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ] };
```

In the above structure, each element in the array `[ ... ]` contains the data for one table row.

In this case, the DataTable uses the `data` option to specify where that array can be found:

```
data: test.data
```

Here is the runnable demo:

```js
var test = {
    "data": [{
        "HistChar_ID": "4",
        "Vorname": "Garnier",
        "Nachname": "de Naplouse"
    }, {
        "HistChar_ID": "2",
        "Vorname": "Robert",
        "Nachname": "de Sable"
    }, {
        "HistChar_ID": "7",
        "Vorname": "Ibn",
        "Nachname": "Dschubair"
    }, {
        "HistChar_ID": "6",
        "Vorname": "Baha ad-Din",
        "Nachname": "ibn Schaddad"
    }, {
        "HistChar_ID": "1",
        "Vorname": "Richard",
        "Nachname": "L\u00f6wenherz"
    }, {
        "HistChar_ID": "5",
        "Vorname": "Wilhelm",
        "Nachname": "von Montferrat"
    }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#example').DataTable({       
    data: test.data, 
    columns: [
        { data: 'HistChar_ID'  },
        { data: 'Vorname' },
        { data: 'Nachname' },
    ]
} ); 

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="thead1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1">HistChar_ID</th>
            <th class="th2">Vorname</th>
            <th class="th3">Nachname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="tfoot1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1">HistChar_ID</th>
            <th class="th2">Vorname</th>
            <th class="th3">Nachname</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

**JavaScript Data Sources**

In the above example, the data is sourced from a JavaScript variable - so at the very least you always need to tell DataTables what the name of the JS variable is, using the [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option.

And, you may also need to tell DataTables where the array of row data can be found in that variable. This is what we needed to do in the above example.

If the JavaScript variable had been structured like this (an array, not an object containing an array)...

```
var test = [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ];
```

...then in that case, we only need to use `data: test` in the DataTable.

---

**Ajax Data Source**

For Ajax-sourced data, things are slightly different. There is no JavaScript variable - there is only a JSON response.

By default, if that JSON response has the following structure (an array of objects called `"data"` - or an array of arrays)...

```
{ "data": [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ] }
```

...then you do not need to provide any additional instructions for DataTables to locate the array. It uses `"data"` as the default value.

Otherwise if you have a different JSON structure, you need to use the Ajax [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to specify where the array is in the JSON response.

For the above example, if you do not provide the `dataSrc` option, that is the same as providing the following:

```
ajax: {
  url: "your URL here",
  dataSrc: "data" // this is the default value - so you do not need to provide it
}
```

This is why your Ajax version "just works" when you only provide the URL:

```
ajax: 'RESOURCES/PHP/Searchfield.php'
```

DataTables is using the default value of `data` to find the array it needs.

And this is why it doesn't work when you use a JavaScript variable called `test` with `data: test`.

---

So, for JavaScript-sourced data, there is no default value. You always have to provide the JavaScript variable name - and maybe additional info for the location of the array in the varaible.

But for Ajax-sourced data, there is a default value (`data`) - and I believe this is only provided for backwards compatibility with older versions of DataTables.

Comment: Finaly it Works. It needed something like this: var Test3 = jQuery.parseJSON(Test); Variable "Test" was interpreted as a String i think. And "Test3" is an Object. Thx for your Answer

Comment: Glad you solved it.